# Сдвинуть все строки датафрейма на +1 к индексу. Чтобы верхняя строка осталась пустой

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

У меня есть датафрейм
Есть ли возможность перенести все данные датафрейма на один индекс ниже(Без удаления данных), чтобы нулевой индекся стал пустым или заполненным(Nan) для дальнейшей работы с ним?

Изначальный датафрейм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже пример того, как хотелось бы, чтобы это выглядело[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все исходные данные и код должны быть в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотами.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408621/add-a-row-at-top-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось как-то длинновато, наверное, можно короче:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['aaa','bbb','ccc'], 'Age': [10,15,20]})
df.index = df.index + 1
df.loc[0] = {}
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df
```

Вывод:

```
    Name  Age
0   NaN   NaN
1   aaa   10.0
2   bbb   15.0
3   ccc   20.0
```

Можно добавить и словарь со значениями-пробелами, но мне не очень понятно, у вас `Age` - строка или число? По-нормальному там должно быть число, а в столбец с числами вы пробел добавить не сможете. Ну и столбец с `NaN`по старой традиции `Pandas` превратился в `float` тут. Всё это решаемо в определённых пределах, но суть действий, я надеюсь, понятна.

Основное тут то, что можно добавить строку в `DataFrame` через `.loc[index]`, указав `index`, которого нет в `DataFrame`. Остальное тут - перенумерация и сортировка индекса.

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь методом [DataFrame.append()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
res = (pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * df.shape[1]], columns=df.columns)
         .append(df, ignore_index=True))
```

результат:

```
In [24]: res
Out[24]:
  Name   Age
0  NaN   NaN
1  aaa  10.0
2  bbb  15.0
3  ccc  20.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось выкрутиться так.
Создал пустой датафрейм с теми же колоннами, и нужной мне строкой и соединил с помощью df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).